# jQuery assign sticky attributes using each function

Tags: jquery, image, variables, global-variables, each

I am building a product configuration page using jQuery and I need to be able to change the colour of the product, in this case a shoe, when the user chooses the corresponding colour option. Each shoe has four component parts that can be specified by the user. Eg. upper colour, sole colour and lace colour and stitching colour. 
I have photos of the shoe in the various colour options and can call them using a standardised file naming convention, Eg:
black-black-black-black.jpg 
and 
red-black-black-black.jpg
black-red-red-red.jpg
etc

I need the product photo to remember the previous choices, so if the visitor chooses red upper, then this is remebered if they then select a blue sole.
So initially we call an all black shoe (black-black-black-black.jpg), then we change that image (red-black-black-black.jpg) when a red upper is chosen and then again(red-red-black-black.jpg) when a red sole is chosen.

My jQuery zoom script (cloudzoom) uses image attibutes to assign the small and large image sizes.

So I need to replace this line with each user choice with the relavant file name and make that selection sticky, until for the next option choice.

I have been looking at this for days now, and would really appreciate some assistance if possible. Thank you.

My code is below and there is a working demo here - http://www.stepto.co.uk/view/product/

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.options ul li a').each(myFunction);


    jQuery('.options ul li a').click(function(){ 
       jQuery('.options ul li a').each(myFunction2)
    });

});

function myFunction2() {
        var embel = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ').pop();
    jQuery(this).each(function(){  

        var target = jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("class");      
            if(target == "optionset1"){
            var base = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ').pop();

            }

            if(target == "optionset3"){
            var sole = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ').pop();

            }
            if(target == "optionset4"){
            var heel = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ').pop();

            }


            var myattributes2 = "useZoom: '#zoom1', image: 'images/small/" + base + "-" + embel + "-" + sole + "-" + heel + ".jpg', zoomImage: 'images/large/" + base + "-" + embel + "-" + sole + "-" + heel + ".jpg'";
            jQuery(this).attr({"class": "cloudzoom-gallery", "href": "#",  "data-cloudzoom" : myattributes2});

    });

}

function myFunction() {

    jQuery(this).each(function(){  


            var base = "black";
            var embel = "black";
            var sole = "black";
            var heel = "black";

            var target = jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("class");      
            if(target == "optionset1"){
            var base = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ').pop();

            }
            if(target == "optionset2"){
            var embel = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ').pop();

            }
            if(target == "optionset3"){
            var sole = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ').pop();

            }
            if(target == "optionset4"){
            var heel = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ').pop();

            }


            var myattributes2 = "useZoom: '#zoom1', image: 'images/small/" + base + "-" + embel + "-" + sole + "-" + heel + ".jpg', zoomImage: 'images/large/" + base + "-" + embel + "-" + sole + "-" + heel + ".jpg'";
            jQuery(this).attr({"class": "cloudzoom-gallery", "href": "#",  "data-cloudzoom" : myattributes2});

    });

}





    <div class="contents" style="width:70%; float:left;">
     <div class="theshoe">
        <img class="cloudzoom" src="images/small/black-black-black-black.jpg" id="zoom1" data-cloudzoom="zoomImage: 'images/large/black-black-black-black.jpg', zoomSizeMode: 'zoom', zoomOffsetX: 0, zoomOffsetY: 0, zoomFlyOut: false, zoomPosition:'inside'" />
    </div>

    </div> 


    <div class="theoptions"  style="width:30%; float:left;">

        <div class="options">
          <h2>Upper Colour</h2>
          <ul class="optionset1">
            <li class="suedeblack black"><a href="#" class="cloudzoom-gallery">black  <img src="images/blank.png"></a></li>
            <li class="suedepurple red"><a href="#" class="cloudzoom-gallery">red  <img src="images/blank.png"></a></li>

      </ul>
<h2>Laces</h2>
          <ul class="optionset2">
            <li class="studblack black"><a href="#" class="cloudzoom-gallery">black laces <img src="images/blank.png"></a></li>
            <li class="studgrey grey"><a href="#" class="cloudzoom-gallery">white laces<img src="images/blank.png"></a></li>


          </ul>
            <h2>Sole</h2>
            <ul class="optionset3">
            <li class="soleblack black"><a href="#" class="cloudzoom-gallery">black sole <img src="images/blank.png"></a></li>
            <li class="solegrey white"><a href="#" class="cloudzoom-gallery">white sole <img src="images/blank.png"></a></li>



          </ul>
            <h2>Stitching</h2>
            <ul class="optionset4">
            <li class="heelblack black"><a href="#" class="cloudzoom-gallery">black stitch <img src="images/blank.png"></a></li>
            <li class="heelgrey white"><a href="#" class="cloudzoom-gallery">white stitch <img src="images/blank.png"></a></li>



          </ul>

         </div>



      </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using $.fn.data.  I won't try and draw up an example, but you can create numerous objects within the data that cover your required info and change them as your needs require.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I have found a jQuery.data example here. Am I on the right track? - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1404-jQuery-Data-Method-Associates-Data-With-DOM-Elements-SWEET-ASS-SWEET-.htm

Comment: Since your suggestion, I have updated my example (http://www.stepto.co.uk/view/product/help2.php) to use the data() method and my colours are stored as objects within that. I now need to manipulate the objects based on the user choice. If you could give me some guidance once more, it would be much appreciated. @user1167442

Comment: I can't tell because I don't know the context of the app, but it seems like you may be over-complicating things.  Specifically what data do you want to know at any given moment?  There might be a very simple solution here.  If you tell me the data (or the type of data)  I will likely be able to provide specific guidance.

Comment: My colour option links each have a custom attribute "cloudzoom" assigned to them in the form <a href="#" class="cloudzoom-gallery"   data-cloudzoom="useZoom: '#zoom1', image: 'images/small/black-black-black-black.jpg', zoomImage: 'images/large/black-black-black-black.jpg'">. I need each link attribute to update when a colour option is selected. So the jpg "black-black-black-black.jpg" will update to "red-black-black-black.jpg" when a red upper is selected. And this updated upper colour is applied to all the option links on the page at once.

Comment: See my solution below.  Let me know if that solves anything for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem I think with resolving it for yourself is the confusing structure of the patterns (what I mean is that with better organized code you would find that the issue was lot a clearer for you).  But, whether that is true or not, here is the basics of how I would do it.

```
 // First a function that will set the image according to the required specs
 var myFunction=function(args){
    var defaults={
           base:'black',
           sole:'black',
           stitch:'black',
           laces:'black',
           imgPath:'images/large/',
           img:function(){
              return this.base + '-' + this.sole + '-' + this.stitch + '-' + this.laces + '.jpg'}
          }
     var options=$.extend({},defaults,args);
     //The above creates a new options object without overwriting the defaults

     $('#zoom1').attr('src',options.img());
    // I will explain this next line in a moment
     if(typeof $('#contents').data('base')==="undefined"){
               $('#contents').data({
                                 base:options.base,
                                 sole:options.sole,
                                 stitch:options.stitch,
                                 laces:options.laces
                                 })
      }
```

There are a couple of ways to do the next piece.  For the sake of simplicity, I am going to assign data to #contents element. 
You may assign this data to any element that suits your purpose.  The point of assigning this data is so that there is a central place to combine the options, so that each click event can reference.  You could also store this in a global variable or in LocalStorage.  For this, we will assign the defaults to #contents on the page load -> That is what the last line of function myFunction does.  If the data is not set, it sets it.
Then an event on page load like so:

```
$(document).bind('load',myFunction});
```

With each $('li a'), we give them a data attribute of data-component and data-color.  Data-component will refer to what type of component they are referencing, i.e. base, sole, etc., and then color will refer to what color you wish to set it.

Then for each link:

```
$('.option li a').on('click',function(e){
      var component=$(this).data('component'),
          color=$(this).data('color');
       // This next line sets the contents data-component referenced to the right color,
       // for example: red laces

       $('#contents').data(component,color);

         var base=$('#contents').data('base'),
             sole=$('#contents').data('sole'),
             stitch=$('#contents').data('stitch'),
             laces=$('#contents').data('laces');
         return myFunction({"base":base,"stitch":stitch,"laces":laces});
    })
```

Even this example is more complicated than it needs to be, but it demonstrates the functionality of utilizing DOM Data.  As you have worked more with the code, and have a deeper relationship with what you are trying to do, you may want to modify the code to suit your needs.  You could call this a pseudo-template.  Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance and your pointers. 
I have used your example and built the functionality that I have been trying to get to. I have updated my example here - 
http://stepto.co.uk/view/product/help5.php 
The method you have described is clean and concise, I really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: One thing about your demo:  Do you preload the images?  They were slow to load on my iPhone, and I bet the image switching would be much smoother with images pre loaded and cached.  Search google.  There are 1000000 turorials in how to do that well.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes, good point. For my demo page I am limiting the number of available colour options, but for my live page I will be offering all colour options. So that will be 4 component parts each with a choice of 5-8 colours. I think this will work out to be about 10-12,000 possible colour combinations for each shoe. I cannot create each photo, so I will be building up the product photo using 4 layered png files. So I think that caching will be impossible in this scenario. Thanks again for all your help, I really do appreciate your time and expertise. @user1167442